# Restriction of $H^3(M_{24}, U(1))$ to $M_{12} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology

$M_{12}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a maximal subgroup of $M_{24}$, where $M_{24}$ and $M_{12}$ are Mathieu groups . Also, it is known that $H^3(M_{24}, U(1)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. I want to find the restriction of a 3-cocycle $\alpha \in H^3(M_{24}, U(1))$ to $M_{12}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

The semi-direct product is defined in the usual manner where the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $M_{12}$ is given by $h(g)=g$ for $h=e$, and $h(g)=\phi(g)$ otherwise, where $h \in \mathbb{Z}_2, g \in M_{12}$ and $\phi$ is an outer automorphism of $M_{12}$.

How do 3-cocycles behave under restriction to maximal subgroups? Would the choice of $\phi$ affect the answer? I would highly appreciate if someone could give me a reference to a result in group cohomology that could help me answer this question.

Comment: Why do you want to know ? What's the background of the question ?

Comment: I am confused by your terminology. Most people would consider $M_{23}$ to be the second largest Mathieu group wouldn't they?

Comment: If anyone knows a way to answer this kind of question (restriction of cohomology to subgroups) with software I'd love to know about it.  GAP happily computes cohomology groups, but as far as I know doesn't give you access to the actual cocycles.

Comment: $M_{24}$ is large enough that it's not obvious how a $3$-cocycle might be presented in reasonable time and space.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thanks for pointing out Geoff. That's a mistake on my part.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies:  The examples I care about are a lot smaller (small finite quotients of PSL_2(Z) restricting to the usual Z/2 and Z/3 subgroups).

Comment: I do not see the group $M_{12} : 2$ on [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M24#Maximal_subgroups).  Do you mean $M_{22} : 2$?  Or is Wikipedia wrong? $M_{12}$ does occur as a subgroup, and I'm happy to believe that $M_{12}:2$ does as well, just not a maximal one.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Did you ever find software for computing restrictions of cohomology classes?

Comment: @Theo: Sadly, no.

Comment: @NoahSnyder One paper I saw managed to workout cocycles for $H^3(M_{24};U(1))$ using the package "HAP" http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/hap.html. Have you used it?