# Is the map $\mathrm H^4(S_{24}) \to \mathrm H^4(M_{24})$ surjective?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

The group $S_{24}$ of permutations of $24$ things has fourth integral cohomology $\mathrm H^4(S_{24};\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/12$.  According to [Sikiric and Ellis](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4291) the [largest Mathieu group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M24) $M_{24}$ has $\mathrm H^4(M_{24};\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/12$.  The Mathieu group is defined in terms of a permutation representation on $24$ things (namely, the coordinate vectors in the extended binary Golay code), and so there is a restriction map $\mathrm H^4(S_{24};\mathbb Z) \to \mathrm H^4(M_{24};\mathbb Z)$.

The number $12$ being somewhat magical, I expect that this map is a surjection.  Is it?  Is the answer to this question known?  My impression of the literature is that $M_{24}$ is just beyond where current technology can fully work out its (2-local, or even $\mathbb F_2$) cohomology.  Compare [this older MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227033/restriction-of-h3m-24-u1-to-m-12-rtimes-mathbbz-2).

Comment: Does M_{24} contain a copy of a medium-sized symmetric group, like S_6?  Maybe it is less intimidating to compute the composite map H^4(S_{24}) --> H^4(M_{24}) --> H^4(S_6), than either map separately.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, here are nine conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups, including the "octad subgroup" (stabilizer of an octad in the $(5,8,24)$ Steiner system, which is isomorphic with $2^4:A_8$) and the "sextet group" $2^6 : (3.S_6)$.

Comment: @DavidTreumann Good idea. But if so, I would expect that the map H^4(S_24) --> H^4(S_6) to be multiplication by 4. It depends, of course, on how the S_6 sits inside the S_24.

Comment: Note also that as soon as a subgroup S stabilizes a point (in the permutation rep), then the map S-->M_24 factors through M_23. But H^4(M_23) = 0, by surprising work of Milgram.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez David Treumann and I decided to answer to [my older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248759/). We have basically got it to the point where the present question is the only (or one of the few) missing ingredient(s). (Compare [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249496/).) I want these answers in order to understand (and prove!) a conjectural behavior in certain conformal field theories --- that behavior is predicted based on expected connections to TMF. I will let David speak to why he is interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to my question is No.  The generator of the $\mathbb Z/12$ part of $H^4(S_{24})$ is $p_1$ of the permutation representation.  That representation restricts to $M_{24}$ to a Spin representation, i.e. one with $w_1=w_2=0$.  For any such representation, $p_1$ is automatically even.

Thus the map $H^4(S_{24}) \to H^4(M_{24})$ has image within the $\mathbb Z/6 \subset \mathbb Z/12$.

Comment: Results of [Dutour Sikiric – Ellis](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4291) and [Gaberdiel – Persson – Ronellenfitsch – Volpato](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.7074) (and, self promotion, [Johnson-Freyd – Treumann](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07587)) in fact imply that the image of $H^4(S_{24}) \to H^4(M_{24})$ is precisely the $\mathbb Z/6$ subgroup. More sharply, $M_{24}$ lifts to the “spin alternating” group $2A_{24}$ (pullback of $S_{24} \to O(24) \leftarrow Spin(24)$), and for $n$ large $H^4(2A_n) = \mathbb Z/24$ generated by the “$p_1/2$”. Ibidim imply that $p_1/2$ generates $H^4(M_{24})$.